# On Click Event in Syncfusion Doughnut Chart on every Slice Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, charts, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am Using Syncfusion library for creating Doughnut Chart in Xamarin Forms. I have created that, but now I what to implement an On click event on every slice of doughnut?? How Can I achieve This? Please help me?

here is my XAML page for doughnut chart

```
<StackLayout>
    <RelativeLayout x:Name="relativeLayout">
        <Label x:Name="myLabel"
               Text="US Sales Total"
               FontSize="30"
               TextColor="White"
               RelativeLayout.XConstraint =
  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                         Property=Width,
                         Factor=0.5,
                         Constant=-260}"
RelativeLayout.YConstraint =
  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                         Property=Height,
                         Factor=0.5,
                         Constant=-380 }" />

        <Label Text="1234"
               FontSize="30"
               TextColor="White"
               RelativeLayout.XConstraint =
  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                         Property=Width,
                         Factor=0.5,
                         Constant = +200 }"
RelativeLayout.YConstraint =
  "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                         Property=Height,
                         Factor=0.5,
                         Constant=-380 }" />


        <chart:SfChart x:Name="sfchart" 
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                 RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}"
                 RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}">
            <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis >
                <chart:CategoryAxis/>
            </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
            <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                <chart:NumericalAxis/>
            </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
            <chart:SfChart.Series>
                <chart:DoughnutSeries x:Name="series1"
                            CircularCoefficient="0.8"
                            DoughnutCoefficient="0.4"
                            StartAngle="0"                                
                            EndAngle="360"
                            EnableDataPointSelection="True"

                            DataMarkerPosition="Inside">
                    <chart:DoughnutSeries.DataMarker>
                        <chart:ChartDataMarker ShowLabel="true" LabelContent="YValue"  />
                    </chart:DoughnutSeries.DataMarker>
                </chart:DoughnutSeries>
            </chart:SfChart.Series>
        </chart:SfChart>
    </RelativeLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [SelectionChanged](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/xamarin/sfchart/Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms~Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.SfChart~SelectionChanged_EV.html) event which fires whenever you have selected a new data point (doughnut slice).

```
<chart:SfChart x:Name="sfchart" 
               SelectionChanged="SfChart_OnSelectionChanged"
               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
               ...
```

And here's the code behind:

```
private void SfChart_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, ChartSelectionEventArgs e)
{
    var chart = sender as SfChart;
    // Do whatever you want here
}
```

It's a shame SyncFusion doesn't provide a command that you could bind to, so if you want to avoid putting stuff to the code behind file, you might want to look into [EventToCommandBehavior](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior/) that let's you implement the event as a ICommand inside your viewmodel.

---

**Edit:** Navigation update

As per you comment, you should do the navigation to the new page within the `OnSelectionChanged` method, like this:

```
private void SfChart_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, ChartSelectionEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedSliceIndex = e.SelectedDataPointIndex;
    Navigation.PushAsync(new SomeNewPage(selectedSliceIndex));
}
```

It's up to you how you define the new page where you navigate to but you most probably want to pass the selected doughnut slice index or some other information to the page. The code above will get you started.

Comment: I want to open another XAML page on clicking any slice in doughnut??
and where I have to define that XAML code?

Comment: @aman I updated my answer. `SomeNewPage` is simply a new ContentPage that you add through the `Add New Item` dialog in Visual Studio. There you can define whatever XAML you want to show on that page.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I was stucked in this problem from last 2 days.

Comment: could you please tell me one more thing??
I want the above XAML page to run same on all the device sizes in android and ios?? what I have to do to achieve this?

Comment: @aman Xamarin.Forms pretty much takes care of scaling the XAML page to fit the different device sizes. You just need to build the UI the right way. I see that you're already using stuff like `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` so the UI probably already works fine on any device. If you have a specific problem with the page and how it runs on different devices, feel free to post a new question. :)

Answer (score 3):

@aman and @hankide

We have also alternative solution for this requirement, you can achieve this requirement by using the MVVM pattern with help of **SelectedDataPointIndex** property in ChartSeries. We need to binding the direct SelectedDataPointIndex property to view model. Please refer the below code snippet.

```
<chart:DoughnutSeries CircularCoefficient="0.8"
                     DoughnutCoefficient="0.4"
                     StartAngle="0"                                
                     EndAngle="360"
                     EnableDataPointSelection="True"
                     DataMarkerPosition="Inside"
                     SelectedDataPointIndex = "{Binding SelectedSlicePage, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

ViewModel Code:

```
    private int selectedSlicePage = -1;
    public int SelectedSlicePage
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedSlicePage;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != selectedSlicePage)
            {
                selectedSlicePage = value;
                NavigateSelectedSlicePage(selectedSlicePage);
            }
        }
    }

    void NavigateSelectedSlicePage(int selectedSlice)
    {
        // Do whatever you want here
    }
```

UG Link :https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfchart/selection

API Link : http://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/xamarin/sfchart/Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms~Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.ChartSeries~SelectedDataPointIndex.html

Thanks,
Manivannan E

Comment: Didn't know about that, certainly a better solution to the problem.